# Single-letter prefix for PHP class constants?

Tags: php, constants

I've noticed many (all?) PHP constants have a single-letter prefix, like `E_NOTICE`, `T_STRING`, etc.  When defining a set of class constants that work in conjunction with one another, do you prefer to follow similar practice, or do you prefer to be more verbose?

```
class Foo {
    // let's say 'I' means "input" or some other relevant word
    const I_STRING = 'string';
    const I_INTEGER = 'integer';
    const I_FLOAT = 'float';
}
```

or

```
class Bar {
    const INPUT_STRING = 'string';
    const INPUT_INTEGER = 'integer';
    const INPUT_FLOAT = 'float';
}
```

Comment: This is really a subjective question left for the wiki.  There is no right or wrong answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up until 5.3 PHP was limited to a single global namespace. Meaning any constants declared with `define` or built into the language required a prefix to partition themselves - namespacing on the cheap, if you will.

About constants themselves: while `E_NOTICE` is easier to type than `ERROR_NOTICE` the former has the major disadvantage of not being self-documenting. When in a global context not only do you need to partition constants out by prefix, these prefixes should also be as descriptive as possible.

Class constants are a slightly different beast, as you'll always be referencing them by class name - partitioning will be built in. So you'll end up with  `Account::STATUS_CONFIRMED` and `Account::STATUS_BANNED`. But if I planned on having several dozen statuses, I'd put these in their own class, e.g. `AccountStatus::CONFIRMED`, `AccountStatus::BANNED`, etc.

Whatever naming convention you decide on for constants the major considerations are partitioning and self-documenting names (verbosity).

Answer (score 2):

For things like constants I prefer to be verbose. I find it makes the code easier to comprehend later (or for folks who didn't write it), and since I use an IDE, I don't usually have to worry about typing the whole long name out when I'm coding.

Comment: I'm actually not worried about typing it so much as eating up half a line of code.  In my particular case, I have a classname that's 18 or 19 characters, plus '::', plus a prefix, underscore, and the constant name, we're talking nearly 40 characters.  I personally don't stick to a strict 80 character line limit, but some folks do.  It feels... inefficient.

Comment: (But at the same time, I completely agree with your logic)

Comment: I hear you 100%. Things can quickly get unwieldy. I don't have a magic bullet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a class, you're better off not using prefixes at all, unless they're extremely meaningful in their contexts. The letter prefix you see with constants is because there were no namespaces in PHP when they were introduced; but classes are some form of namespacing, so this isn't really necessary.

If you are, however, going to use a prefix anyways, I suggest you use the most meaningful one—that is, the full word instead of a single letter. I wouldn't have guessed myself that `I` meant `INPUT`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to be more verbose

```
class Bar {
    const INPUT_STRING = 'string';
    const INPUT_INTEGER = 'integer';
    const INPUT_FLOAT = 'float';
}
```

This makes the code easier to read for the next person who has to work on the code. You could consider adding your own framework-prefix to the constants (eg.: XYZ_INPUT_STRING) that'll decrease the change of having a conflict with other components that you might use. A downside of being more verbose is that variablenames tend to get longer, but a good IDE supports code completion so you don't have to type the whole variable name.

Comment: No +1 for you unless you explain why and not copy/paste the question.

Answer (score 0):

The reason most PHP constants have the prefix is to namespace them, so that . For example, in `E_USER_ERROR`, the `E_` does two things:

1. It tells you that the constant is related to the error handling system
2. It makes it so that if you want to have a constant called `USER_ERROR` in your application, you can.

In PHP5, we can use class constants, so namespacing is no longer necessary. See for example the [`DATE_` constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types). The equivalent of `DATE_ATOM` is `DateTime::ATOM`, where `DateTime` is the PHP class that deals with dates. `DATE_ATOM` still exists, presumably for legacy reason, but were that constant created today, it would simply be called `DateTime::ATOM`.

In your case, it might make sense to define an input class that would have these constants:

```
class input {
    public const STRING='string';
    public const INTEGER = 'integer';
    public const FLOAT = 'float';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefixes are used to namespace symbols. Eg. since constants are declared in the global scope, you can use a prefix to specify the context of it and avoid clashing with other uses of the symbol in a different context.

Since class constants already exists in a context (the class), there is really no need to prefix it further. Instead of your example, this would probably make more sense:

```
class Input {
  const STRING = 'string';
  const INTEGER = 'integer';
  const FLOAT = 'float';
}
```

That said, I find that constants (class or global) are generally not something I use very much in PHP. You can usually replace a constant with a more specific methodname, and this generally make the code much more maintainable. For example, instead of something like this:

```
$foo->addParameter("foo", Input::STRING);
```

You could do this:

```
$foo->addStringParameter("foo");
```

It's easier to read *and* it's easier to write.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike C and friends, in dynamic languages we rarely, if ever, need pre-declared constants.  because descriptive string  values work just as fine. There is no real benefit of using

```
if($account->status == AccountStatus::CONFIRMED)
```

compared to

```
if($account->is('confirmed'))
```

The latter is more readable and requires less code.

Before you start writing an indignant comment, look how jQuery does it: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ . 'hide', 'toggle', 'fast' etc are actually constants, they are simply not declared as such.

Comment: What happens when the class' internal behavior changes and the constant needs to be modified, though?  The use of declared constants makes code maintenance far more manageable.

Comment: I would prefer `$account->isConfirmed()`.